# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jakarta-ee

"it work fine in eclipse but when i create jar and run it will give me this exception.This is non web spring boot application i am using which i supposed to run as standalone jar"

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
                    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.findResource(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]



at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
                    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
                    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
                    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
                    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
                    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.findResource(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:58) ~[extension-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
                    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
                    at java.net.URLClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
```

Comment: It looks like your classpath isn't set-up correctly

Comment: How can i fix it?

Comment: ya but i use spring boot so it is adding all the dependancy jar into it !!!

Answer (score 3):

It might be a bit late but I encounted the same error recently on Windows and fixed it with a dirtly hack. I hope future people looking for the same question will find this useful for their problem.

First of all, eclipse "run" your Spring Boot app in a different way. It does not do `java -jar foo.jar` but reference all classes and libraries directly i.e. `java -classpath xxx/target/classes:a.jar:b.jar...`. So soetimes running in eclipse will behave differently.

I suppose you are running into the same situtation as I did which is you have a Spring Boot app and you want to package it as executable jar and you are referencing external dependencies and could not fix what went wrong inside those external dependencies.

What I found out was that somewhere inside the external library I was using is generating a temporary file and reading it using Java's `ClassLoader` but Spring Boot's `LaunchedURLClassLoader` could not handle Windows's "x:\" syntax

In my case, it was

```
URL findResource(name): C:\foo\bar.xml
```

So the hack is to build your own `LaunchedURLClassLoader` and replace it in the executable jar. If you unpack the excutable jar, you will find `LaunchedURLClassLoader.class` under `org\springframework\boot\loader`. The idea is to reaplce `C:\foo\bar.xml` to `file:///C:/foo/bar.xml` so Java ClassLoader will know how to deal with the file.

```java
...

package org.springframework.boot.loader;
...

public class LaunchedURLClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

    ...

    @Override
    public URL findResource(String name) {

        // This is where I added the dirty hack
        if (name.contains(":\\") && !name.startsWith("file:///")) {
            System.out.println("URL findResource(name): " + name); // just for you to debug
            name = "file:///" + name.replace("\\", "/");
            System.out.println("URL findResource(name): Reaplced to " + name); // just for you to debug
        }

        Handler.setUseFastConnectionExceptions(true);
        try {
            return super.findResource(name);
        }
        finally {
            Handler.setUseFastConnectionExceptions(false);
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with JasperReport and I solved it when I opened the JRXML file in a text editor like (Notepad, notepad++). Inside this file there were several references to the "name" tag and, one of them, was referencing an image in a fixed path on the hard disk, causing, when I ran the application on another machine, directly through the jar  file, thows the error "java.lang .IllegalArgumentException: name"

To solve this, I removed a hard reference to image, like showed below:

["D:\Projetos\REPORT\Logo.png"]

and passed the image as an ImputStream in the report parameter to JRXML